# Log Sobolev inequality uniform in parameters

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, pr.probability, inequalities, convex-geometry, optimal-transportation

Fix a positive integer $N$. For $\theta \in [0,2\pi]$, set $\sigma_k(\theta) :=(\cos(k\theta),\sin(k\theta)) \in S^1$ for each integer $1\leq k\leq N$. Now for vectors $x_1,\ldots,x_N\in \mathbb{R}^2$, consider the probability measure $\mu_{X_N}$ on $[0,2\pi]$ which is proportional to

$$e^{\sum_{k=1}^N x_k\cdot\sigma_k(\theta)}d\theta,$$

where $\cdot$ denotes the Euclidean inner product on $\mathbb{R}^2$.

> **Question.** Does $\mu_{X_N}$ satisfy a logarithmic Sobolev inequality (LSI) with a constant $C_{LSI}$ which is *uniform* in the vectors $x_1,\ldots,x_N$? That is, for all test functions $f$,
> $$\int_{0}^{2\pi} f^2\log\left(\frac{f^2}{\int_{0}^{2\pi}f^2d\mu_{X_N}}\right)d\mu_{X_N} \leq C_{LSI}\int_0^{2\pi} |f'|^2d\mu_{X_N},$$
> with $C_{LSI}$ independent of $X_N:= (x_1,\ldots,x_N)$ but possibly depending on $N$.

It's trivial, by the Holley-Stroock perturbation lemma and the fact that the uniform distribution satisfies a (dimension-free) LSI, to show that $\mu_{X_N}$ satisfies an LSI possibly depending on the data $X_N$. Since the LSI constant is continuous in the data $X_N$, the difficulty is proving the constant is uniformly bounded in $X_N$ when the norm of $X_N$ is large.

There is a characterization of the LSI for measures on $\mathbb{R}$ due to [Bobkov-Gotze](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1682772) and refined by [Barthe-Roberto](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2052235), which I state below from the latter reference.

> **LSI criterion.** Let $\mu,\nu$ be Borel probability measures on $\mathbb{R}$, such that $d\nu = \rho dx$ for some density $\rho$. Let $C$ be the optimal constant in the inequality
>
> $$\int_{\mathbb{R}}f^2\log\left(\frac{f^2}{\int_{\mathbb{R}}f^2d\mu}\right)d\mu \leq C\int_{\mathbb{R}}|f'|^2d\nu.$$
>
> Then $\max\{b_-,b_+\} \leq C \leq 4\max\{B_-,B_+\}$, where for a median $m$ of $\mu$,
> $$b_+ := \sup_{x>m}\mu([x,\infty))\log\left(1+\frac{1}{2\mu([x,\infty))}\right)\int_{m}^x \frac{1}{\rho},$$
> $$B_+ := \sup_{x>m}\mu([x,\infty))\log\left(1+\frac{e^2}{\mu([x,\infty))}\right)\int_{m}^x \frac{1}{\rho},$$
> $$b_- := \sup_{x<m}\mu((-\infty,x])\log\left(1+\frac{1}{2\mu((-\infty,x])}\right)\int_x^m\frac{1}{\rho},$$
> $$B_- := \sup_{x<m}\mu((-\infty,x])\log\left(1+\frac{e^2}{\mu((-\infty,x])}\right)\int_x^m\frac{1}{\rho}.$$

Using this characterization, [Zhang et al.](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2854732) (see Theorem 2.1) showed a uniform LSI in the case where $N=1$. Their argument is based on estimating the integrals in the LSI criterion. It extends by scaling to the case where at most one of the $x_i$ is nonzero, but trying to estimate the necessary integrals to apply the above criterion in the general case seems difficult, if not intractable when $N$ is large. I'm curious if anyone has encountered a similar estimate and has suggestions on how to proceed---aside from roll up my sleeves and start estimating integrals.

Comment: It seems quite unlikely, since for >1, you should expect the multimodality of the potential to cause more and more difficulty for mixing (if you interpret LSI in terms of the convergence of Markov processes etc.); possibly an Eyring-Kramers-type result could formalise this? My guess is that this is precluded in the =1 case by the unimodality of $\sin$; for =2 this should generically fail.

Comment: @πr8 Thank you! Indeed, my interest in this question has to do in part with the asymptotic behavior of the gradient flows associated to the corresponding free energy. I am not familiar with these Eyring-Kramers type results you mention (I don't come from probability), but I will take a look at them.

Comment: For a more function-centric approach to showing that the uniform LSI cannot hold, I could recommend finding an $x$ so that $\mu_x$ has two modes, and designing a test function $f$ which is $+1$ near the first mode, and $-1$ near the second mode; rescaling this $x$ by a diverging factor (i.e. taking the low-temperature limit), one should see that the ratio between the two sides of the inequality will degrade arbitrarily, reflecting the difficulty of transitioning between the two modes.

Comment: @πr8 In other words, starting with $N=2$, one can have a nontrivial combination of 2 Dirac point masses in the weak closure of the measures $\mu_{X_N}$ (take a trigonometric  polynomial with 2 equal global maxima and amplify) , but the LSI clearly fails in that limit case, so no uniform bound is possible.